# ember-data: tell if a computed property is readonly

Tags: ember.js

Can I tell if a computed property is readonly?

I want to avoid trying to set a property that is readonly and this code being triggered:

```
  if (this._readOnly) {
    throw new Error('Cannot Set: ' + keyName + ' on: ' + obj.toString() );
  }
```

Comment: did you tried the approach from my answer? since I haven't tested it would like to know if it worked

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `obj` is an instance of `DS.Model` you could try something like this (haven't tested it tough):

```
var meta = obj.metaForProperty(keyName);
if (meta && meta.options.readOnly) {
  throw new Error('Cannot Set: ' + keyName + ' on: ' + obj.toString() );
}
```

Hope it helps.